# How to subtract one object array literally from another object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, reduce

I think my question is pretty easy but as I am beginning to learn javascript I'm stuck with the following. 
I have 2 object arrays which contain some same Ids which can be multiple duplicates. I want to subtract the same Ids in the arrays from each other with plain javascript no libraries. I found this filter method but it removes all the objects with the criteria. 
I expect only the amount of Ids removed fulfilling the criteria which can be found in the array to be subtracted.

Here is my example:

```
var filter = [{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},{"Id":"124","Name":"OPL-00074051","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"}]   
var filter2 = [{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074051","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"}]     
var newFilter = filter2.filter(o => !filter.find(o2 => o.Id === o2.Id &&  o.arrayPicklist === o2.arrayPicklist));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newFilter));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy6fcgrc/29/

I expect:

```
newFilter = [{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074051","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"}]
```

Comment: Question is not clear? What do you want to acheive?

Comment: No Just remove the ids which are the same based on amount of same ids between the different arrays. GSSwain came up with the answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var filter1 = [{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},
{"Id":"124","Name":"OPL-00074051","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"}]

var filter2 = [{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},
{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074051","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},
{"Id":"123","Name":"OPL-00074045","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"}]


var props = ["Id","Name", "arrayPicklist"];

var result = filter1.filter(function(o1){
    // filter out (!) items in result2
    return !filter2.some(function(o2){
        return (o1.Id === o2.Id && o1.arrayPicklist===o2.arrayPicklist) ;          // assumes unique id
    });
}).map(function(o){
    // use reduce to make objects with only the required properties
    // map to apply this to the filtered array as a whole
    return props.reduce(function(newo, arrayPicklist){
        newo[arrayPicklist] = o[arrayPicklist];
        return newo;
    }, {});
});
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it removes all. If I have a 2 arrays with the same objects 1 array with 2 the same 1 array with one if i substrat I expext to be left over with an array with 1 object. If both arrays have 1 object which is th same i expect an empty array. In this case I always end up empty no matter hom many duplikates see:http://jsfiddle.net/yxz7hqz9/